# Filter out random username after string

Tags: linux, grep, json

I have a full list of API status with lots of information like that.
I need to grep the name of the username so I can send it to another file or variable.

For example:

```
[{"id":"1onyc4b1otgmtrmw37h83rjs9w","create_at":1542718790947,"update_at":1542728017634,"delete_at":0,"username":"ivan.ivanov","auth_data":"".
```

I need to grep the string after "username":
In the end to have only **ivan.ivanov** or whatever the name will be.

Comment: yes it is a full json, I just don't show the whole one as it is has sensitive information. Just giving a small part of it, if that is enough

Comment: okay, that's good, then you can use a json parser. Anyways, in your question you should provide a valid example of your input, even when shortened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this was a proper json string, you could parse it with `jq`:

```
your_api_call | jq -r '.[]["username"]'
```

or

```
jq -r '.[]["username"]' file
```

But the string you provided is not proper json. It's missing the closing brackets (`]}`) at the end and has a `.` instead.

`jq` should be available in most package managers, e.g. install it with:

```
sudo apt install jq
```

---

If you somehow **need** to use `grep` and have `pgrep` / `grep -P` available:

```
grep -Po '"username":"\K[^"]*'
```

Comment: Actually that works, but shows me for only the first occurrence. Can it be done for every string that contains username? * UPDATE* IT Works with grep , thanks a lot

Comment: did you see my update using `[]` instead of `[0]` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following command and it worked fine:

```
echo "[{"id":"1onyc4b1otgmtrmw37h83rjs9w","create_at":1542718790947,"update_at":1542728017634,"delete_at":0,"username":"ivan.ivanov","auth_data":""." |
  sed "s/,/\n/g" |
  awk -F ":" '/username/{print $NF}'
```

output

```
ivan.ivanov
```

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you could do with [jtc](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc):

```
bash $ jtc -w'<username>l+0' your.json
"ivan.ivanov"
bash $
```

if your json has multiple usernames all will be printed, otherwise (if you need just one) drop '+0' - the first only will be printed